# Java script filter on array of objects and push result's one element to another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have a array called `data` inside that array I have `objects`.
An object structure is like this

```
{
id:1,
especial_id:34,
restaurant_item:{id:1,restaurant:{res_name:'KFC'}}
}
```

I want to pass a `res_name` eg:- KFC

I want an output as a array which consists all the `especial_ids`

like this
myarr = [12,23,23]

I **could do something like this for that**. But I want to know what is more elegant way to do this.

```js
const data = [
  {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'McDonalds'}},
  
  {id:1,especial_id:8,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}},
  
  {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Sunmeal'}},
  
   {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}},
];

let temp = data.filter(element => element.restaurant_items.res_name == 'kfc')

let myArr = [];

temp.forEach(element=> myArr.push(element.especial_id));

console.log(myArr)//[8,6]
```

Comment: just use ```let myArry = data.filter(element => element.restaurant_items.res_name == 'kfc')```

Comment: After "filter", instead of forEach you can directly use "map" to get especial ids. You can check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this. It uses "Array.filter" and "Array.map"

```js
var data = [
  {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'McDonalds'}},
  
  {id:1,especial_id:8,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}},
  
  {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Sunmeal'}},
  
  {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}},
];

function getEspecialIdsByName(name) {
  return data.filter(d => d.restaurant_items.res_name.toLowerCase() == name.toLowerCase())
             .map(d => d.especial_id)
}

console.log(getEspecialIdsByName('Kfc'))

console.log(getEspecialIdsByName('Sunmeal'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `reduce` to push elements which pass the test to the accumulator array in a single iteration over the input:

```js
const data = [
  {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'McDonalds'}},
  {id:1,especial_id:8,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}},
  {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Sunmeal'}},
   {id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}},
];
console.log(
  data.reduce((a, { especial_id, restaurant_items: { res_name }}) => {
    if (res_name === 'Kfc') a.push(especial_id)
    return a;
  }, [])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
const data = [{id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'McDonalds'}},{id:1,especial_id:8,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}},{id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Sunmeal'}},{id:1,especial_id:6,restaurant_items:{id:5,res_name:'Kfc'}}];

let result = data.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(c.restaurant_items.res_name === 'Kfc') a.push(c.especial_id);
  return a;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```